# How to display customized number field

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to create a customised number button which will function same as normal number field.

But need to create a number field like in the below image.

[image: Number field]

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
            <div class="form-group1 col-sm-4">

            <label class="control-label l_font" for="height">HEIGHT*</label>
                <br>
        <input class="form-control1 wid" type="number" name="feet" autocomplete="off" ng-required="true" ng-model="model.height" min="1" max="12"/>        
        <input class="form-control1 wid" type="number" name="inches" autocomplete="off" ng-required="true" ng-model="model.heightinches" min="0" max="10"/>
                <br>
        <p class="hintleft" readOnly>feet</p>
    <p class="hintright" readOnly>inches</p>

</div>
            </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4"> 

            <div class="form-group2 col-sm-2">

            <label for="weight"  class="control-label l_font">WEIGHT*</label><br> 
    <input type="number" name="kilo" class="form-control1 wid1" autocomplete="off" ng-required="true" ng-model="model.weight" min="1"/>
    <p class="hintleft" readOnly>kg</p>

            </div>
          <div class="form-group2 col-sm-2">      
        <label for="chest"  class="control-label l_font">CHEST*</label> <br>
    <input type="number" name="chest" class="form-control1 wid1" autocomplete="off" ng-required="true" ng-model="model.chest" min="0" max="100"/>
    <p class="hintleft" readOnly>inches</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hope this is helpful for you: https://codepen.io/komarovdesign/pen/PPRbgb

Comment: MDL means?   Thanks this is exactly I want but I am using angularjs. The above code is in JQuery

Comment: when i click on "+" button it is taking the value as " ". So i tried by setting default value but it is not working. I am using angularjs.